# some confusion about infimum and supremum concepts>

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

which of the following is true ?

$1.\sup_{0 <ε<1/2}\sup(A_{ε})<1$

$2.0<ε_{1}<ε_{2}<\frac{1}{2}\implies \inf(A_{ε_1})\lt \inf(A_{ε_2})$

$3.0<ε_{1}<ε_{2}<\frac{1}{2}\implies\sup(A_{ε_1})>\sup(A_{ε_2})$

$4.\sup(A_{ε_1}\bigcap\mathbb Q)=\sup\Bigl(A_{ε_1}\bigcap(\mathbb R$\ $\mathbb Q)\Bigr)$

I SEARChing  this types of problem in Rudin ( analysis) book but I could not find this kind of problem and concept in any real anaylsis book.

so i very much confused about this problem

pliz help me

Comment: I believe the concept of infimum and supremum can be found in any real analysis book

Comment: yes tony ma....but   how to approach this kind problem ?

Comment: why downvotes  ????

Comment: see my answer (I may add more detail if you couldn't understand), for downvote, I believe, will not exist, if you show more research effort, such as what did you did about this question and where does the question come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1-3) Give any $0\le\epsilon\le\frac{1}{2}, \sup A_\epsilon=\sup(0,1-\epsilon)=1-\epsilon$ and $\inf A_\epsilon=\sup(0,1-\epsilon)=0$ (Do you know why?)

Q4)Consider $A_\epsilon$, while $0\le\epsilon\le\frac{1}{2}$, forall $a<1-\epsilon$, exists $b\in \mathbb Q$ (Do you know why?) such that $a<b<1-\epsilon$, while $b$ can be taken to be inside $A_\epsilon$, that is, $b\in(A_\epsilon\bigcap\mathbb Q)$, since clearly $1-\epsilon$ is an upper bound of $(A_\epsilon\bigcap\mathbb Q),\sup(A_\epsilon\bigcap\mathbb Q)=1-\epsilon$, similarly, $\sup\Bigl(A_\epsilon\bigcap(\mathbb R\bigcap\mathbb Q)\Bigr)=1-\epsilon$.

Comment: First of all  i want to thanks a lots for this @Tony ma  ..as  i did n't understand  how  $\sup\Bigl(A_{ε_1}\bigcap(\mathbb R$\ $\mathbb Q)\Bigr)$ = 1- ε

Comment: Try to search in google: Elementary Analysis: The theory of Calculus by kenneth A.Ross(Second Edition):    Section 4.7(Maybe you already know) and **exercise 4.12**. Then imitate the proof I give to d), $\sup(A_\epsilon\bigcap\mathbb Q)=1-\epsilon$

Comment: thanks  alots @tony ma,,i accepted ur answer